# How do I debug an x-terminal-emulator that fails to start?

Tags: gnome-terminal, openbox

I am trying to start a terminal window in openbox. However, the window never pops up. I tried to execute

```
$ x-terminal-emulator
$ echo $?
1
```

The same happens if I try to run `gnome-terminal`. There is no output. However, this runs perfectly well under xfce4. Where is the output of this logged? How can I fix this?

Added Later: The problem does not exist when I do `sudo startx` to start openbox. How do I get `gnome-terminal` work as me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that this was a permission issue. I deleted every file in mu home directory and started XServer again with `startx` and it worked.

I should have instead done `chown -R ...` and `chgrp -R ...`.

The first time I logged in, `lightdm` created these files and `lightdm` runs as root and the files created belonged to root :-(